# .NET Core Web API not working after being deployed to Azure

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a simple .NET Core Web API application—the one made by Visual Studio when a new project is created. I want to deploy it to an Azure App Service via FTP as part of a Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2017 build job, which is successful:

[image]

However, when trying a `GET` request such as the following URL:

```
http://somerandomname.azurewebsites.net/api/values
```

All I get is a 404 with the text:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

From Kudu, I get the following error:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: You have to wait a few minutes until the deploy was finished. Are you using Docker?

Comment: Well, you kinda need a web.config if you are going to host in IIS :)

Comment: @AlvaroCantador - no docker yet, just a plain IIS (I think)

Comment: @juunas I was suspecting that. What do I need to put in it?

Comment: @tomab Take a look https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: @tomab Kestrel deploys doesn't require it

Comment: @AlvaroCantador how do I know if it's a Kestrel deploy? And does the Azure App Service works like IIS (i.e. does it need this web.config or not)?

Comment: @tomab You can specify your deployment requirements in your TFS 2017 jobs, theres you can point to a Windows VM, or a Azure App Service with Windows.

Comment: @tomab Also you can run in the powershell: `While(1) {ps | sort -des cpu | select -f 15 | ft -a; sleep 1; cls}` and check if theres any kestrel or dotnet proccess

Comment: I understand your solutions. What I don't understand is how Azure App Service works in comparison with a local host iis server and what configuration does it need.

Comment: have you tried visual studio's deploy? just to check if it works?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane did it, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So a web.config is needed. The one which VS 2017 populates with some default values when a new item is added it's not good. Using a VS 2017 web api default project, I've published it using right-click menu. That worked seamlessly. I've took the web.config from Azure web service and integrated it in my own project, changing only the dll name. Now, when a build job is running on behalf of TFS, it has the web.config among the files which are uploaded via FTP to Azure app service.

Here is the web.config I've ended with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <remove name="aspNetCore"/>
  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
</handlers>
  <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Somerandomname.WebApi.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem using Azure DevOps.

I decided to try publishing by right click deploy to a different app service, so that I could see what web.config I should have.

The right click deployed app did show /api/values where as the devops app did not.

The only difference in the web.configs were the location of stdoutLogFile

Using right click deploy

```
stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout"
```

Using devops

```
stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout
```

However right click deploy had included all my 3rd party dlls, so I am thinking somehow my devops pipeline nuget settings need correcting.

I am [asking about that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684714/how-do-i-get-my-nuget-packages-to-deploy-with-azure-devops-build)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the .net 5 API project. It works fine on local machine but after publishing to Azure WebApp it gives the error

> This ****.azurewebsites.net page can’t be found

In my case following lines were missing from Startup.cs

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            }
        );
```

Adding these lines in the configuration section of the startup.cs fixed the issue.