# How to get the logs from an Azure App Service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops

I have an Azure Pipeline which deploys my application to an Azure App Service.

My Application is connected to a Key Vault, and in the Key Vault is registered my connection string for my database.

In local, I can communicate with the database but not with the Key Vault I admit it's because of the ActiveDirectory registeration and I don't really need to access it in local. Everything else works properly.

But after the deployment, I can't test my application. I always got 404 error for the Swagger.

I'm almost sure that I'm getting an error while connecting to the Key Vault, so I need to be able to see the error logs of my application. Unfortunately I can't see them.

What I've tried to do is the following :

I've added this piece of code to the `public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)` method of the `program.cs` :

```
 Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging(logging => logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics())
            .ConfigureServices(serviceCollection => serviceCollection
                .Configure<AzureFileLoggerOptions>(options =>
                {
                    options.FileName = "azure-diagnostics-";
                    options.FileSizeLimit = 50 * 1024;
                    options.RetainedFileCountLimit = 5;
                })
                .Configure<AzureBlobLoggerOptions>(options =>
                {
                    options.BlobName = "log.txt";
                }))
```

But when I go to the kudu of my App Service, I can't find any logs which talks about an exception in my code. And I have no "log.txt" or "azure-diagnostics-*" file.

How can I see a possible exception on an Azure App Service ?

**-- EDIT 1 --**

I cannot see the same options as shown by @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT :

[image]

Comment: > I always got 404 error for the Swagger.

The reason for this is that the deployment or default ASP.NET Core template does not include a default document in the root directory of the web site.

Comment: Do you have web.config in your application ? Please refer this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51558155/net-core-web-api-not-working-after-being-deployed-to-azure)

Comment: Please refer this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#azure-log-streaming-1)

Comment: I hadn't a web.config in my application, but I used kudu and seen that Azure generated one for me. Anyway, I added one to my application and tried everything from the SO Thread but it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

To see the logs/log files of the Azure Web App Service, need to do few settings which are the following below:

- Navigate to the App Service in Azure > ***App Service Logs*** under ***Monitoring*** section > switch on the few settings as shown in below screenshot:

[image]

Now, Click on "***Save***" button to save the changes.

- After a few seconds, the "***Web server logging***" is enabled for the App Service.
- Go to FileZilla and Login with your azure app service credentials and traverse to root folder of the App Service
  [image]

Run/Browse the application now.
[image]

Refresh the ***Log files*** folder in File Zilla and there is ***http*** folder created along with ***RawLogs*** sub folder inside it.

[image]

There are some tools to read the log file data in a readable format like Log browsers as the log file contains the browser name, request details in columns format and values of the request details, error information etc..,

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I don't have the exact same settings available as yours, maybe it's a possible issue source ? I've edited my main post to add a screen capture

Comment: Have configured Application Insights to your project?

Answer (score 0):

For viewing the App Service logs, first enable it in the `App Service logs` menu of the Azure App Service.

[image: Enable App Service Logs]

Once you enable the `App Service Logs`, select the `Log Stream` and you will be able to see the logs.

[image: Log Stream - Azure App Service]

Comment: Unfortenately, the log stream does not show any error... if I had an error coming from the deployment, for example if the database isn't accessible, would it be shown here ?

Comment: If it is related to deployment you will be able to see the response in the Azure DevOps console right?

Comment: Sorry I mean, during the start of the application. The deployment is going well but if an error occurs during the execution of the program.cs or Startup.cs, would it be shown in the log stream ?

Comment: One quick question - Did you enable Swagger in the Production environment? If you didn't change it, by default it will be enabled on the Development environment only.

Comment: I've also tried a direct endpoint without going through Swagger. I still have a 404 error

Comment: Did you check the Kudu console -whether it is deployed properly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240298/discussion-between-m-ozn-and-anuraj).